# How to throw an exception based on if else check blocks in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, flutter-widget

I have been trying to implement the exceptions while calling Rest APIs, I have done a basic implementation of exceptions in a try-catch block.
But I need to throw error dialogs on different status codes i.e: either 200 or 500

I am attaching my code snippets in order to better understand what exactly I am trying to implement.

```
try {
  var response = await client
      .post(
          Uri.https(
              "api base url", "api end point"),
          body: param)
      .timeout(Duration(seconds: TIME_CONST))
      .catchError(handleError);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return UserCheck(
      user: data['user_exists'],
    );
  } else {
    print("The response status is not 200");
    return param;
  }
} on SocketException {
  throw FetchDataException('message', 'url');
} on TimeoutException {
  throw ApiNotRespondingException("message", "url");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Have been stuck on this problem for quite a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Switch and case](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case) for that.

```
switch(response.statusCode){
  case 200: // Show success screen
  break;
  case 403: // Show dialog for error 403
  break;
  case 500: // Show dialog for error 500
  break;
  case 503: // Show dialog for error 503
  break;
  default: // Show dialog for other errors
  break;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use a switch case

Comment: i want to implement this in if else block

Comment: Why not using switch case for that? It's more readable and easier to use than an if else block.

Comment: because I just need two cases either 200 or 503.
Anything outside these two response codes, catch block handles the error

Comment: Well in your description you have actually 4 cases (200, 403, 500, 503)

Comment: Hey @quoci,
Have edited the description.
Now it says only two response codes.

Comment: Well now can you help me